# Retain Output on Stack-Update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I wrote a Cloudformation template that creates a stack with a DynamoDB Table:

```
     "FeedStageDynamoTable" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
        "UpdateReplacePolicy" : "Retain",
        "Properties" : {
            "TableName" : { "Fn::Sub": [ "feed-${Year}-${Environment}-table", { "Year": {"Ref" : "BundleYear" }, "Environment" : {"Ref" : "DeployEnvironment"}} ]},
            "AttributeDefinitions" : [
              {"AttributeName" : "Guid", "AttributeType" : "S"}
            ],
            "KeySchema"            : [
              {"AttributeName" : "Guid", "KeyType" : "HASH"}
            ],
            "ProvisionedThroughput" : {
                "ReadCapacityUnits" : "2",
                "WriteCapacityUnits" : "2"
            },
            "StreamSpecification": {
                "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
                }
        }
    }
```

and an Output for the Table's Stream:

```
"Outputs" : {
    "FeedStageTableStreamArn": {
        "Description" : "The security group ID to use for public web servers",
        "Value" :  { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["FeedStageDynamoTable", "StreamArn"] },
        "Export" : { "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-FeedStageDynamoTableStreamArn" }}
    },
```

The output is used by a lambda function from another template (for the second stack):

```
    "NotifyWebConsumer" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "Environment": {
            "Variables" :  {
                "EnvironmentCodename" :  { "Fn::Sub": [ "${Environment}", { "Environment" : {"Ref" : "DeployEnvironment"}} ]}
                }
            },
            "Handler": "AmazonServerlessStageWebUpdate::AmazonServerlessStageWebUpdate.Functions::NotifyWebConsumer",
            "FunctionName": "NotifyWebConsumer",
            "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.1",
            "CodeUri": "",
            "MemorySize": 256,
            "Timeout": 30,
            "Policies":[{  "Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${DeployEnvironment}-LambdaExecutionPolicy"} }],
            "Role":{"Fn::GetAtt": ["NotifyConsumerRole","Arn"]},
            "Events": {

            }
        }
    }
```

...

```
"EventSourceMapping": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping",
            "Properties": {
             "EventSourceArn": {  "Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "StageEnvironment-FeedStageDynamoTableStreamArn"} },
              "FunctionName" : {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "NotifyWebConsumer", "Arn"
                    ]
        },
              "StartingPosition" : "LATEST"
              }
        }
```

After I published both stacks I can not update the first one anymore, because the output stream is in use by the second stack. Now my question: is there a cloudformation property like "UpdateReplacePolicy": "Retain" for outputs? Or is there any other way to update the first stack without deleting the second one?

Comment: If you try to update the first stack without impacting DynamoDB or the output stream, what is the message you receive?

Comment: You cannot change an output which is imported by another stack, period. (And therefore, the resource whose value you're exporting.) There's a longwinded way to accomplish this: create a new resource, export it, change your downstream template to import that new resource instead, then make your modifications to your original resource/output, deploy, then change your downstream template back to the original output, then delete your temporary resource/output.

Comment: You can also hard code the existing output as a part of the above process. That allows you to make changes to the source of the output whilst not changing the output itself. Of course if you are using this stack in multiple places you'd have to either use a map or pass in the output value as an input variable.